# UE4 My skeletal mesh won't simulate physics when in a socket

Tags: unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint

I am making a scale with chains that hold a plate.

[The Scale Asset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5hyta.png)

I have the chain as a skeletal mesh with a physics asset. The part that the chains hang onto have sockets.
[The chain](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MpyBn.jpg)
When I try to attach my chain to the asset, I have issues:

1) When I put the chain into the blueprint actor and assign it to its parent socket via the details panel...the chain will just fall off when simulated rather than hanging from where the socket is.

2) When I attach the chain to a socket via blueprints, the physics won't simulate at all. The chains just stay rigid.
[example of the construction script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DdRtu.png)

How can I get the chains to stay in place...while simulating physics?
Is there a better way I am just not using?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

On your chain, in the physics asset, you need to select the physics capsule on the bone that is attaching to the socket and set it’s physics from default/simulating to kinematic. It disables physics on that one bone and will anchor instead of fall when you attach it.